# Flink have problem with removing checkpoint _metadata from google cloud storage

Tags: apache-flink

I deploy flink job in Google Kubernetes Engine(GS) with enabled checkpointing.
I configure GS filesystem with configuration described here
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/filesystems/gcs/

I also want to encrypt data stored in GS which i do with configuration described here
https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/v2.2.4/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md#encryption-csek

using this variables in flink config

- fs.gs.encryption.algorithm
- fs.gs.encryption.key (not set by default)
- fs.gs.encryption.key.hash (not set by default)

When I start flink job, it works and checkpoints are done. But when checkpoints are discarded, in log i see errors like this
"<path in gs to /_metadata>" and from google API error 400 and message
"The target object is not encrypted by a customer-supplied encryption key".

I checked that _metadata files are not encrypted.
I don't understand this behavior because I set encryption in flink config and the _metadata are done by flink. Since Flink created them, it should be able to delete them as well.

It turns out that flink creates a _metadata file for checkpoint as not encrypted but tries to delete them as encrypted files, which causes an error in the google API.

Currently, I could not correct this behavior. The checkpoints themselves work fine and everything is removed from gs if I do not run encryption.
Maybe someone knows what to do when running encryption on GS but checkpoint data were completely deleted.

Comment: The _metadata is written by the job manager, while the rest of the checkpoint files are written by the task managers. Could it be that the job manager doesn't have the necessary configuration in place?